# My 2 tailed sample significance is not showing in paired sample t test result on SPSS

Tags: spss, t-test

I am trying to do a paired sample t-test analysis with SPSS, but the column that should hold the two-tailed significance is split in two: "1 sided p" and "2 sided p". I do not know how to interpret this result. Please help me out.

I want to either get the result I am looking for, which is the two-tailed significance, or understand how to interpret the results I am getting, which is 1 sided p and 2 sided p. I'm not permitted to add images yet so here is a link to the report:

C:\Users\User\Documents\paired sample t test stack.png

Thank you in advance.

I tried to run the test about 4 times with different variables and tried clicking on other options before running the analysis but the result is the same.

Comment: 2-sided == two-tailed

Answer (score 2):

I unfortunately don't have SPSS anymore and cannot see your link, but alas I have looked on YouTube and found a video that shows the output of a paired samples t-test for SPSS. Here is what they have and I have highlighted what I suspect your interpretation issue is:

[image]

Basically, SPSS by default gives you the result of a one-tail and two-tail test automatically without really saying which is "correct" (this is what "one-sided" and "two-sided" mean by the way). If you are only interested in testing if there is a significant difference in either direction (two-tailed), then you only use the two-tail test p value. So in your case, just ignore the "one-sided" p-value and use the "two-sided" p value instead.

Comment: Wow thank you so much. that's exactly what my issue was. I appreciate the help

Comment: Sure thing. If you feel my answer was helpful, feel free to click the check mark next to it in order to accept it.